# Flutter Android Studio not showing Flutter Application on new Project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dialog, new-project

I have successfully installed ANdroid Studio and Flutter on my Windows 11 laptop. When i lauch my Android Studio and i select New Flutter app, it is showing me this. Can anyone tell me why. And how to Fix it[image: This is the dialog showing]

How will it show the correct dialog which is this[image: This is the dialog i wanted to see]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

After clicking on "New Flutter Project", select Flutter from the left panel.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions:

Step1: Click on create New Flutter Project

Step2: Click on Flutter in the left side panel, select Flutter path, and click next. [See Image Link Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjEEp.png)

Step3: Give your project a name, make sure Project Type in the left panel has Application selected. In Organization below Project Type, either type your name ass a webaddress (johndoe.com) or use a website you own. Leave all other settings and click create.
[See Image Link Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yiw9.png)